# Keep submit button disabled until form is complete and confirming password

Tags: javascript, html, forms, disabled-input

I know that there are a bunch of posts about this already, but no matter what I try, nothing works for my form.

I simply want the submit button to be disabled until all fields are filled in, and I want `$mypassword` checked to equal `$myconfirmpassword` before submitting.

If you can find something that works. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!

Obviously, some things are hidden for privacy purposes, as you can't see my CSS and PHP info.

```
<div id="container" style="height:700px;">
<a href="login.php" class="anchor"><div id="back">
 <h2>Back</h2>             
 </div></a>
    <div id="registration_container" >
   <table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FF9">
    <tr>
<form name="form3" method="post" action="check_finish_registration.php">
        <td>
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FF9">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><strong>Complete Registration </strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="2000">First Name</td>
                <td width="6">:</td>
                <td width="294"><?php echo $fname ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="2000">Middle Name*</td>
                <td width="6">:</td>
                <td width="294"><input type="text" name="mymname" id="mymname"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="2000">Last Name</td>
                <td width="6">:</td>
                <td width="294"><?php echo $lname ?></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td width="2000">Create a Username*</td>
                <td width="6">:</td>
                <td width="294"><input type="text" name="myusername" id="myusername"></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td width="2000">Create a Password*</td>
                <td width="6">:</td>
                <td width="294"><input type="text" name="mypassword" id="mypassword"></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td width="2000">Confirm Your Password*</td>
                <td width="6">:</td>
                <td width="294"><input type="text" name="myconfirmpassword" id="myconfirmpassword"></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td width="2000">Enter your Sigma Number*</td>
                <td width="6">:</td>
                <td width="294"><input type="text" name="mysnumber" id="mysnumber"></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td width="2000">E-Mail Address*</td>
                <td width="6">:</td>
                <td width="294"><input type="text" name="myemail" id="myemail"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>


                <td width="2000">* required field</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input   type="submit" id='register' value="Register"disabled='disabled'></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
</form>

     </tr>
    </table>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: If you are amendable to using jQuery, the Validate plugin will accomplish this fairly easily.

Comment: Pls move the form tags outside the table tags for valid html

Comment: I moved the form tags outside of the table. thanks mplungjan for the tip. I am not opposed to using jquery, I just never learned it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of disabling the submit button, why don't you just try to validate the form so that until the user enters the correct values, the form will not be submitted to the database? And about the password and confirm password fields validation

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function passwordConfirm() {
        var confirmPass = document.getElementById("confirmpassid").value
        if(pass != confirmPass) {
            alert("Mismatching passwords");
        }
      }
```

Comment: I had a similar code that I wrote myself, the problem I found was when to call the code. I tried just putting it in the <head> section. But then it didn't call. I tried putting it before </body> and the body onload function. The problem there is, obviously they are not filled and matching, the page only just loaded. I tried a setInterval function, but it still didn't work. So after reading a lot of examples, I feel like it is easier to disable the button, but I do need a validate password code as well.

Comment: You can do all the validations in a separate javascript file and call that page in the header section.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use this but if you want you may give it a try ([jQuery](http://jquery.com) would be good)

```
var  els=[];
window.onload=function(){
    var inputs=document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(i=0; i<inputs.length;i++)
    {
        if(inputs[i].type=='text' || inputs[i].type=='password')
        {
            if(inputs[i].name!='fname' && inputs[i].name!='lname')
            {
                inputs[i].onkeyup=check;
                els.push(inputs[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

function check()
{
    var isValid=true;
    for(i=0; i<els.length;i++)
    {
        if(!els[i].value.length) 
        {
            isValid=false;
            break;
        }
        else isValid=true;
    }
    var reg=document.getElementById('register');
    if(isValid && matctValidInputs()) reg.disabled=false;
    else reg.disabled=true;
}

function matctValidInputs()
{
    var re=/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{3}$/;
    var ps=document.getElementById('mypassword');
    var cps=document.getElementById('myconfirmpassword');
    var snum=document.getElementById('mysnumber');
    var mail=document.getElementById('myemail');
    if(ps.value.length>5 && ps.value==cps.value && re.test(mail.value) && isNumber(snum.value))
        return true;
    else return false;
}

function isNumber(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n) && n.length>5;
}
```

**Before you test the demo:**

1. Password must be 6 characters and match with confirm password.
2. The `Sigma Number` must be a number and minimum 6 digits.
3. Email must match a valid email (very basic regex)
4. No alerts/notifications given.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/p3Nwd/4/).

Comment: I tried, it didn't work. I am not opposed to using jquery, I just don't know how. Do you know how to make it work with my code?

Answer (score 0):

just copy and paste my code.there might be few things you might wanna improve.If it is so,let me know

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fnc()
{
var name=document.getElementById("mymname").value;
var username=document.getElementById("myusername").value;
var password=document.getElementById("mypassword").value;
var confirmpassword=document.getElementById("myconfirmpassword").value;
var number=document.getElementById("mysnumber").value;
var email=document.getElementById("myemail").value;
if(name!='' && username!='' && password!='' && confirmpassword!='' && number!='' &&  email!='')
 {
   document.getElementById("register").disabled=false;
 }
 else
 document.getElementById("register").disabled=true;
}
function check()
{
var password=document.getElementById("mypassword").value;
var confirmpassword=document.getElementById("myconfirmpassword").value;
if(password!=confirmpassword)
    {
        alert("password missmatches");
        return false;
    }

}
</script>
<div id="container" style="height:700px;">
<a href="login.php" class="anchor"><div id="back">
<h2>Back</h2>             
</div></a>
<div id="registration_container" >
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FF9">
<tr>
<form name="form3" method="post" action="check_finish_registration.php" onSubmit="return check()">
    <td>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FF9">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><strong>Complete Registration </strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="2000">First Name</td>
            <td width="6">:</td>
            <td width="294"><?php echo $fname ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="2000">Middle Name*</td>
            <td width="6">:</td>
            <td width="294"><input type="text" name="mymname" id="mymname" onKeyUp="fnc()"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="2000">Last Name</td>
            <td width="6">:</td>
            <td width="294"><?php echo $lname ?></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td width="2000">Create a Username*</td>
            <td width="6">:</td>
            <td width="294"><input type="text" name="myusername" id="myusername" onKeyUp="fnc()"></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td width="2000">Create a Password*</td>
            <td width="6">:</td>
            <td width="294"><input type="text" name="mypassword" id="mypassword" onKeyUp="fnc()"></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td width="2000">Confirm Your Password*</td>
            <td width="6">:</td>
            <td width="294"><input type="text" name="myconfirmpassword" id="myconfirmpassword" onKeyUp="fnc()">

            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td width="2000">Enter your Sigma Number*</td>
            <td width="6">:</td>
            <td width="294"><input type="text" name="mysnumber" id="mysnumber" onKeyUp="fnc()"></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td width="2000">E-Mail Address*</td>
            <td width="6">:</td>
            <td width="294"><input type="text" name="myemail" id="myemail" onKeyUp="fnc()"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>


            <td width="2000">* required field</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input   type="submit" id="register" value="Register" disabled='disabled' "></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
  </form>

 </tr>
 </table>
 </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: I put it in and reread to see if there were any typos, and as far as I can tell your script is fine. But it still didn't work. I can still submit the form without the fields being populated.