# if i click ok in alert box all text box become empty?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

i got error, For example i am having 4 text boxs name,dob,age and mail-id. in this if i entered name,dob and age but i am not entering mail-id. if i click submit the alert box appear in that mail id is empty like that. If i click ok in that alert box rest of the three field name,dob,age also got empty if i click ok.

```
 <script>
 function validateForm(){
var x=document.forms["registration_form"]["user_name"].value
 if (x==null || x=="")
           {
                alert("Please Enter The Name");
return false;

}
else{ true}
var x=document.forms["registration_form"]["dob"].value
if (x==null || x=="")
           {
                alert("Please Enter Date Of Birth");
                return false;

}
  else{ true}
var x=document.forms["registration_form"]["age"].value
if (x==null || x=="")
           {
                alert("Please Enter Age");
return false;

}
else{ true}
var x=document.forms["registration_form"]["number"].value
if (x==null || x=="")
           {
                alert("Please Enter The Mobile Number");
return false;

}
else{ true}
    var x=document.forms["registration_form"]["mail"].value
var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
     if (x==null || x=="" || atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
             {
                  alert("Please Enter a Valid Mail-Id and Must fill it");
                  return false;

           }
           else{ true}
           var x=document.forms["registration_form"]["address"].value
   if (x==null || x=="")
           {
                  alert("Please Enter The address ");
                return false;

           }
else
{
return true;
}
}      
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you do `else{ true}` ???

Comment: also show the code where this validation function is called

Comment: Use better variable names than `x`; drop `else` clauses that you are not using; use strict equality, or rely on the truthiness of the input value; automate all this code by using an associative array holding the input fields and their error messages and a generic loop.

Comment: check firebug for troubleshooting..

Comment: Nothing in the code you posted modifies the input fields. It's happening in some other part of your code.

Comment: You should have post your `form/HTML` code too , anyways, [take a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380824/keep-submit-button-disabled-until-form-is-complete-and-confirming-password/12381682#12381682), this may give you an idea.

Answer (score 2):

remove `x==null` in your condition check

```
  else
    {
    true 
    }
```

this block is unnecessary;

Comment: ok I can understand but My problem is, For example i am having 4 text boxs name,dob,age and mail-id. in this if i entered name,dob and age but i am not entering mail-id. if i click submit the alert box appear in that mail id is empty like that. If i click ok in that alert box rest of the three field name,dob,age also got empty if i click ok.

Comment: ok try document.getElementById('field_id').value=="" for every field instead of reading by form name

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are calling this function from your form's onSubmit method.
If so, ensure you also are using  **return**. For example:

```
<form ... onSubmit="return validateForm()" />
...
</form>
```

This will ensure that form is not submitted when your validation function returns false.